# css animation text not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

update: it is working if i use direct link instead of rocketscript

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        i am trying to rotate words with css animation and tried everything but its not working.
```

i want to rotate the name one by one.
here is my jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/knfwom9n/

the word New year should change and new words like diwali , womens day should come but everything works except animation.

here is full code

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .cf-hidden {
            display: none;
        }

        .cf-invisible {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://something.com/js/css/stylewish.css">
    <link href="http://something.com/img/icon.png" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="row container">
            <div class="col s12">
                <div class="valign-wrapper">
                    <div class="col l3 hide-on-small-only">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s12 l6 offset-l3">
                        <div class="valign card-panel  z-depth-2">
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="create-idea">
                                        <img class="center" src="http://something.com/js/css/wishes-sharing-2.svg" height="100px" width="100px" alt="Wishes">
                                        <img class="center" src="http://something.com/js/css/wishes-sharing.svg" height="100px" width="100px" alt="Wishes">
                                        <br>
                                        <section class="cd-intro">
                                            <h5 class="cd-headline letters type">
                                              <span>Create Your Wishes For </span>
                                              <span class="cd-words-wrapper">
                                                <b class="is-hidden" style="opacity: 1;"><i class="out">D</i><i class="out">i</i><i class="out">w</i><i class="out">a</i><i class="out">l</i><i class="out">i</i></b>
                                                <b class="is-hidden" style="opacity: 1;"><i class="out">F</i><i class="out">r</i><i class="out">i</i><i class="out">e</i><i class="out">n</i><i class="out">d</i><i class="out">s</i><i class="out">h</i><i class="out">i</i><i class="out">p</i></b>
                                                <b class="is-hidden" style="opacity: 1;"><i class="out">B</i><i class="out">i</i><i class="out">r</i><i class="out">t</i><i class="out">h</i><i class="out">d</i><i class="out">a</i><i class="out">y</i></b>
                                                <b class="is-hidden" style="opacity: 1;"><i class="out">C</i><i class="out">h</i><i class="out">r</i><i class="out">i</i><i class="out">s</i><i class="out">t</i><i class="out">m</i><i class="out">a</i><i class="out">s</i></b>
                                                <b class="is-visible" style="opacity: 1;"><i class="in">N</i><i class="in">e</i><i class="in">w</i><i class="in"> </i><i class="in">Y</i><i class="in">e</i><i class="in">a</i><i class="out">r</i></b>
                                              </span>
                                            </h5>
                                        </section>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field col s12 ">
                                        <input id="username" onKeyDown="validateAlpha();" type="text" class="validate" required="" maxlength="15">
                                        <label for="username">Enter Your Name</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <select id="wishes-select" onChange="selected();" name="wishes-select" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                                        <option value="0" hidden="" disabled="" selected="">Choose your Wishes</option>
                                        <option value="friendship">Friendship Day</option>
                                        <option value="birthday">Birth Day</option>
                                        <option value="magic">Women's Day</option>
                                        <option value="diwali">Diwali (India)</option>
                                        <option value="xmas">Christmas</option>
                                        <option value="new">New Year</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="input-field col s12" id="bnames" style="display:none;">
                                        <input id="bname" type="text" onKeyDown="validateAlpha();" class="validate" required="" maxlength="15">
                                        <label for="bname">Birthday Boy/Girl Name</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-field col s12" id="bnamess" style="display:none;">
                                        <input id="bwords" type="text" onKeyDown="validateAlpha();" class="validate" required="" maxlength="50">
                                        <label for="bwords">Birthday Quotes</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <p id="error-display" style="display:none;"></p>
                                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" onClick="create();" type="submit" style="width:100%" name="action">Create</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="page-footer blue-grey darken-1">
        <div class="footer-copyright">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4" href="http://something.com/" target="_blank">Create Wishes</a>
                <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="http://something.com" target="_blank">something</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script data-rocketsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketoptimized="true"></script>
    <script data-rocketsrc="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js" type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketoptimized="true"></script>
    <script data-rocketsrc="http://something.com/js/wish.js" type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketoptimized="true"></script>
    <script data-rocketsrc="http://something.com/js/hoped.min.js" type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketoptimized="true"></script>

    <div class="hiddendiv common"></div>
</body>
```

any help will be great.

js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/knfwom9n/

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:   http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did you use any js? can you show?

Comment: @DonaldWu thanks for your reply. i solved the issue just by changing the urls of js file to usual url ratherthan rocketscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the issue just by changing the urls of js file to usual url rather than rocketscript 
 like this

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

rocketscript was causing problem